# How do you get Jacobi symbol $[\frac{3}{8}]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do you get $[\frac{3}{8}]$? Answer is -1, but how do you get that?

Comment: I thought [Jacobi symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) $\left(\frac an\right)$ is defined only for odd $n$.

Comment: That's true but when you input "Jacobi symbol(3,8)" in the http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jacobi+symbol%283%2C8%29 you get -1. Might be false.

Comment: Maybe that's supposed to be a [Kronecker symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSymbol.html) instead of a Jacobi symbol...

Comment: @alvoutila: *Mathematica* actually generalizes `JacobiSymbol[]` to effectively act like `KroneckerSymbol[]`.

Comment: Dear @Martin: +1 for your comment, and thanks for all your editing work!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol